# read sent mails from mail server

Tags: java

i know how can we retrive the mails from INBOX folder...but now i want to retrieve mails from SENT ITEMS folder...i am using imap to retrieve the data...
Let me know what parameter i should pass in this function to get mails from SENT ITEMS folder
`Folder folder=store.getFolder("inbox");`i should change the inbox as some stirng i want to know that string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem....
i used this code to list out the folders from mail server
and pass those values in getFolder() function...it's working fine..

```
Folder[] folderList = store.getDefaultFolder().list();
        for (int i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(folderList[i].getFullName());
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not a standard name here.  The [IMAP spec](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2060.html) requires that the inbox be called "INBOX", but no other folders are specifically defined.  It's just a name of a folder after all - some providers will use "Sent", some will use "Sent Items" and you might even see some other variants about.

I'd recommend listing the folders that the server knows about, and selecting the appropriate one from there (either interactively, or perhaps grepping for "sent" in the name if running headless).  A better option overall might be to make this a configurable parameter (if your application already has a properties file).

Of course, if this is a throwaway project you could just hard-code the value for the specific server in question.  But if you want to do it properly, you'll need to be flexible.

Comment: thank you Andrzej Doyle...do you know how can we list out the folders that the server knows

Answer (score 1):

Gmail stores sent mails under a folder called `Sent Mail` inside `[Gmail]` folder. So I was able to get the sent mail folder through this;

`Folder sentMail = store.getFolder( "[Gmail]" ).getFolder( "Sent Mail" );`

Answer (score 0):

This code will retrieve all mails and will print the contents and store in local if have any attachment

```
public class MailReader {
        Folder inbox;
        public MailReader() {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            try {           
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
                store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "username",
                        "password");
                /* Mention the folder name which you want to read. */
                inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
                System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : "
                        + inbox.getMessageCount() + " "
                        + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());

                /* Open the inbox using store. */
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

                /*
                 * Get the messages which is unread in the Inbox Message messages[]
                 * = inbox.search(new FlagTerm( new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
                 */
                Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
                /* Use a suitable FetchProfile */
                FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
                fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
                fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
                inbox.fetch(messages, fp);

                try {
                    printAllMessages(messages);
                    inbox.close(true);
                    store.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Exception arise at the time of read mail");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(2);
            }
        }

        public void printAllMessages(Message[] msgs) throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");
                printEnvelope(msgs[i]);
            }
        }

        /* Print the envelope(FromAddress,ReceivedDate,Subject) */
        public void printEnvelope(Message message) throws Exception {
            Address[] a;
            // FROM
            if ((a = message.getFrom()) != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
                }
            }
            // TO
            if ((a = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println("TO: " + a[j].toString());
                }
            }
            String subject = message.getSubject();
            Date receivedDate = message.getReceivedDate();
            String content = message.getContent().toString();
            System.out.println("Subject : " + subject);
            System.out.println("Received Date : " + receivedDate.toString());
            System.out.println("Content : " + content);
            getContent(message);
        }

        public void getContent(Message msg) {
            try {
                String contentType = msg.getContentType();
                System.out.println("Content Type : " + contentType);
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
                int count = mp.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception arise at get Content");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {
            // Dump input stream ..
            if (p.getFileName() == null) {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("filename:" + p.getFileName());
            System.out.println(p.ATTACHMENT);
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            File file = new File(p.getFileName());
            FileOutputStream fout = null;
            fout = new FileOutputStream(p.getFileName());
            // If "is" is not already buffered, wrap a BufferedInputStream
            // around it.
            if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
                is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            }
            int c;
            System.out.println("Message : ");
            while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
                fout.write(c);
            }
            if (fout != null) {
                fout.close();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new MailReader();
        }
    }
```

Comment: reference : 1.http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/javamail.html                                                                                                         2.http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/java-code-to-receive-mail-using-javamailapi/